# Get currently logged on interactive user for a remote machine?

Tags: .net, windows, windows-xp, authentication

How do I find out what user, if any, is currently logged on to some remote Windows XP machine *interactively*? .NET code would be great or any command-line utility that I can call from code. SysInternals **psloggedon**, [as suggested on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/162496/how-to-find-out-who-is-currently-logged-on-via-vnc), almost works, but it doesn't tell me which session is interactive.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to use the [Remote Desktop Services API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892075.aspx).  WTSOpenServer + WTSEnumerateSessions + WTSQuerySessionInformation.  Of course this won't work if the Terminal Services service isn't running, but I don't know of another way to get this information.

Comment: Hmm, I get an "Access denied" error when calling `WTSOpenServer`, even though I'm an admin on the remote machine and psloggedon works fine.